# How to group a list of dict into sub-lists using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

input is something like

```
[
  {"name": "person 1", "age": 20, "type": "student"},
  {"name": "person 2", "age": 19, "type": "worker"},
  {"name": "person 3", "age": 30, "type": "student"},
  {"name": "person 4", "age": 25, "type": "worker"},
  {"name": "person 5", "age": 17, "type": "student"}
]
```

and the desired output when grouped by the "type" field should be

```
[
  [
    {"name": "person 1", "age": 20, "type": "student"},
    {"name": "person 3", "age": 30, "type": "student"},    
    {"name": "person 5", "age": 17, "type": "student"}
  ],
  [
    {"name": "person 2", "age": 19, "type": "worker"},
    {"name": "person 4", "age": 25, "type": "worker"}
  ]
]
```

I have the following code to do it with itertools

```
from itertools import groupby

input = [
  {"name": "person 1", "age": 20, "type": "student"},
  {"name": "person 2", "age": 19, "type": "worker"},
  {"name": "person 3", "age": 30, "type": "student"},
  {"name": "person 4", "age": 25, "type": "worker"},
  {"name": "person 5", "age": 17, "type": "student"}
]

input.sort(key=lambda x: x["type"])
output = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(input, key=lambda x: x["type"])]
```

which gives the result correctly. However For larger amount of data I think using pandas should be more efficient, but now it seems I can't quite figure out how to accomplish the above with pandas. The code I have now somewhat works but I don't think it's efficient at all.

```
import pandas as pd

input = [
  {"name": "person 1", "age": 20, "type": "student"},
  {"name": "person 2", "age": 19, "type": "worker"},
  {"name": "person 3", "age": 30, "type": "student"},
  {"name": "person 4", "age": 25, "type": "worker"},
  {"name": "person 5", "age": 17, "type": "student"}
]

indexes = [list(v) for k, v in pd.DataFrame(input).groupby(["type"]).groups.items()]
output = [[input[y] for y in x] for x in indexes]
```

I'm pretty sure the above code is a very wrong way to use the pandas groupby functionality, so any help on how to do it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: _"However For larger amount of data I think using pandas should be more efficient,"_, not sure this is true

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(input).groupby('type').apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_list()
```

Slightly faster,

```
pd.DataFrame(input).groupby('type').apply(
    pd.DataFrame.to_dict, orient='r').tolist()
```

```
# [[{'age': 20, 'name': 'person 1', 'type': 'student'},
#   {'age': 30, 'name': 'person 3', 'type': 'student'},
#   {'age': 17, 'name': 'person 5', 'type': 'student'}],
#  [{'age': 19, 'name': 'person 2', 'type': 'worker'},
#   {'age': 25, 'name': 'person 4', 'type': 'worker'}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

What I will do

```
l1=[[y.iloc[0].to_dict() for  z in y.iterrows()] for _ , y in pd.DataFrame(input).groupby('type')]
Out[254]: 
[[{'age': 20, 'name': 'person 1', 'type': 'student'},
  {'age': 20, 'name': 'person 1', 'type': 'student'},
  {'age': 20, 'name': 'person 1', 'type': 'student'}],
 [{'age': 19, 'name': 'person 2', 'type': 'worker'},
  {'age': 19, 'name': 'person 2', 'type': 'worker'}]]
```

And also if only need to match with key with the value , you can check with `itertuples`

```
l=[list(y.itertuples()) for _ , y in pd.DataFrame(input).groupby('type')]
Out[256]: 
[[Pandas(Index=0, age=20, name='person 1', type='student'),
  Pandas(Index=2, age=30, name='person 3', type='student'),
  Pandas(Index=4, age=17, name='person 5', type='student')],
 [Pandas(Index=1, age=19, name='person 2', type='worker'),
  Pandas(Index=3, age=25, name='person 4', type='worker')]]
```

---

Compare

```
l[0][0].age
Out[263]: 20
l1[0][0]['age']
Out[264]: 20
```